# how to download the google maps sdk for android studio?

Tags: android, google-maps, class, package, edit

I need to download the whole package of Google maps for android, but I have searched and I only get the link of Gradle, I do not know how to download the package, since I need to edit some kind of that package

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start

Comment: I have added all the packages but I still leave the classes as blocked